# Albino elephants

Tags: zoology, mammals

How many albino elephants are there across the world? There is no information on the total number of albino elephants across the world except for the few albino elephants captured by people.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this howstuffworks.com article](https://health.howstuffworks.com/skin-care/problems/medical/albinism6.htm) who itself poorly cite a paper with a broken link (!), albinism in mammals occur in typically about 1 in every 10,000 births. The claim is quite definitely not trustworthy but that's all I found!

There are an estimated 450,000 - 700,000 African elephants and between 35,000 - 40,000 wild Asian elephants. So, if we believe that about 1 birth in 100,000 is an albino, then there are between 30 and 100 albino elephants in the world.

See also [this quora post](https://www.quora.com/How-many-white-elephants-albino-elephants-are-there-across-the-world)

Comment: [This](https://mdc.mo.gov/conmag/2005/06/all-about-albinism) is the website/magazine howstuffworks.com is referring to. They don't cite anything but "some researchers".